# Facebook custom widget to show real time data

Tags: facebook, widget

I have a website for voting to a particular event. As a marketing in facebook, I wanted to show real time voting stats to the users who are following my facebook group. Can someone guide me to write a custom widget which pull data from my service (through json/rest api) and render it real time on facebook.

Comment: Render it where on Facebook?

Comment: Yes render it on Facebook

Comment: I meant where on Facebook do you want to render it?

Comment: Render it to a facebook page I own.

Comment: Well I guess best place would be as the top post on the facebook page